# Right click not functioning in touchpad in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, touchpad, lenovo

i am not able to right click on my touch pad in Ubuntu. how to solve the problem?

Comment: please, post here the output of `synclient -l`

Comment: Add your hardware details.

Comment: how to add hardware details. i mean what hardwhere details u want?